# How to hide public post containing ACF plugin custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post where the user can modify all site texts in custom fields created with ACF plugin. Thing is, I don't want this post to show at all in any page. I tried changing it status to private, but this makes all the texts from the custom fields disappear from the website. How can I filter only this particular post out from all posts listings? Is there some way to filter it out in functions.php?

EDIT: I'm using the PRO version, in case anyone wonders about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to store `all site texts in custom fields` in a post? 
You could better register an options page, and store all the details there. Than you don't have to hide any posts.

Register a acf options page:

```
<?php
// Add main options page
acf_add_options_page( array(
    'page_title'     => __( 'Options', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_title'     => __( 'Options', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_slug'      => 'theme-options',
    'capability'     => 'manage_options',
    'position'       => 999
) );
add_filter('init', 'options_pages');
?>
```

Th get fields from an options page, you need to pass the 'option' parameter to `get_field()` or `the_field()` like this:

```
<?php echo get_field('your-field-name', 'option'); ?>
```

You can read more about options fields in the ACF documentation:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_page/

Comment: Can I keep the current theme page code where the content comes from have_rows('a_group') and get_sub_field('field_from_a_group') functions? Will it still work?

Comment: Yes, your existing code should still work, just dont forget to add the 'option' parameter of you're retrieving options fields.

Comment: I applied the 'option' parameter but the content vanished. Also, the line add_filter('init', 'options_pages') generated a warning: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'options_pages' not found or invalid function name in /usr/local/var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Comment: The error was in another function, where I load parts of my theme. Inserting the 'option' parameter there too fixed it now. Also, I removed that line with the add_filter, warning stopped and nothing wrong happened.